# org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds

Tags: solidity, remix, java, wrapped-tokens

Yesterday I could deploy the code successfully, but today onwards I am facing the below error. I tried to reduce/increase the gas fees yet the error is still not resolved.

If anyone is willing to resolve this issue I will be happy.
[I created a java wrapper class and run the code it was worked well but now its not creating a smart contracting and not sending the transaction hash.]

##### The error:

```
The balance of the Ethereum account is: 1366450650000000000 Wei
Exception in thread "main" org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction: 0xcfe40d9661b3e264b64abec24d5ce455d829196c06094f11242fa0cccbc6065c
    at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.getTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:61)
    at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.waitForTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:167)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:127)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:364)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.create(Contract.java:419)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:453)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$7(Contract.java:605)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:42)
    at blockchain_testing4.Block_Testing4.main(Block_Testing4.java:93)
```

Comment: Hey, may help if you add how you are setting the transaction parameters. Gas prices can have gone up since yesterday, if you didn't adjust fees enough to account for that, it could still be the issue. Share amounts you are using, how you set it, and the network to compare against.